# Spring Boot [How to properly use .exit]

Tags: spring-boot

Apparently, as I  read in different threads, Closing ConfigurableApplicationContext uses .exit, and I read that it can be implemented in many ways. I tried to use it like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = app.run(args);
    app.exit(applicationContext);
}
```

When I run the program w/out the exit part, it runs okay, but now when I placed the exit part, even the login page does not display

Answer (score 0):

What are You trying to achieve?

exit is a method to stop context (and therefore your application). 
It's used to assure gracefully shutdown of context. Followed by the possibility to return exitCode You fancy.

```
public static void closeApp(SpringApplication app, ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
    final int exitCode = 5;
    ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator = new ExitCodeGenerator() {

        @Override
        public int getExitCode() {
            return exitCode;
        }
    };
    app.exit(context, exitCodeGenerator); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = app.run(args);
    shutdown(app, applicationContext); // this shoud prints "Process finished with error code 5"

}
```

}